# Як перекласти "отражающий элемент"

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Як перекласти *отражающий элемент*? Йдеться про елемент конструкції дзеркал автомобілю.

> Сплошной резистивный *отражающий элемент* выполняется в виде пленки на
>   обратной стороне оптического элемента, одновременно выполняющий
>   функцию отражающего слоя.
>
> Процитовано [звідси](http://avto-i-avto.ru/ustrojstvo-avto/zerkalo-zadnego-vida-vnutrennee-i-naruzhnye-kakie-byvayut-i-zachem-nuzhny.html)

Пошуки в інтернеті дали такі варіанти: *відбиваючий елемент*, *відражаючий елемент*, *дзеркало*. Який з них найбільше підходить?

Comment: Дієприкметникові звороти не притаманні українській мові. Їх варто уникати. `Отражение`,  в контексті світла/хвиль, [перекладається](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Відбиття_(фізика)) як   `відбиття`/`віддзеркалення`. Склавши до купи отримуємо `елемент відбиття` або `елемент віддзеркалення`.

Comment: У [коментарі на фейсбуці](https://www.facebook.com/ukrse/posts/1913089772150393?comment_id=1913137982145572) Василь Барвінок пише: (світло)відбивний елемент.

Answer (score 5):

> Процесові прикметники, тобто віддієслівні прикметники, що називають:
>
> 1. здатність бути підданим дії (інтеґровний, йонізовний, (з)руйновний, синтезовний, фільтровний)
> 2. призначення виконувати дію (інтеґрувальний, йонізувальний, синтезувальний, фільтрувальний)
> 3. здатність виконувати дію (йонізівний, руйнівний, фільтрівний), як окрема мікросистема найменувань видових понять у науковій мові ще не були об’єктом спеціального дослідження.
>
> <sub>// [ПРОЦЕСОВІ ПРИКМЕТНИКИ В НАУКОВІЙ МОВІ](https://r2u.org.ua/node/162)</sub>

У вашому випадку підходить пункт два, тобто **відбивальний елемент**.

Також можна подивитись варіанти, що їх пропонує [r2u](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%20&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on).

> - Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)
>     **Отража́ющий** – відбивни́й.
>     • *Предметы*, -**щие** *лучи* – ре́чі, що відбива́ють промі́ння.
> - Російсько-український словник 1930р. (О. Ізюмов)
>     **Отражающий** – що відбива́є.
> - Російсько-український словник технічної термінології 1928р. (І. Шелудько, Т. Садовський)
>     **Отражающий** – відбивни́й.
> - Російсько-український словник з інженерних технологій 2013р. (Марія Ганіткевич, Богдан Кінаш)
>     **отража́ющий** відбива́льний, відобража́льний
> - Словник українсько-російський 1927р. (А. Ніковський)
>     **Відбивни́й** – отражающий, отражательный.

Comment: …і e2u (для [reflecting](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=reflecting&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on), [reflective](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=reflective&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on)).

Comment: будь ласка, додайте інформацію з r2u й e2u у свою відповідь, вона від того дуже виграє.

Answer (score -4):

"Отражение" перекладається як "вiдображення".
Таким чином, “отражающий элемент” - "вiдображаючий елемент".

Comment: Пепепрошую, але цей переклад не лише дослівний, а й — у випадку автомобільних дзеркал, адже контекст зазначає автор запитання — неправильний. «От**об**ражение» — відображення,  а «отражение» — відбиття, відзеркалення тощо. Хоча я не буду заперечувати, що в частині випадків рос. «отражение» і укр. «відображення» можуть значною мірою перетинатися, але в загальному випадку (зокрема в фізиці) рос. «отражение» і рос. «от**об**ражение» можуть позначати дуже різні речі.

Comment: Крім того, наша традиція вимагає підкріплювати свої твердження посиланнями на словники, реальні приклади вживань тощо (адже інакше читачам дуже важко розсудити, де правильна відповідь, а де неправильна).

Comment: У будь-якому разі, дякую за спробу!